# How to install phpmyadmin on Mint

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin, installation, linux-mint

I'm new to Linux. I'm trying to install phpmyadmin on Mint.

I tried the following:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server
sudo dpkg-reconfigure phpmyadmin
sudo service apache2 restart`

But I can't access it via : `localhost/phpmyadmin`.

I have installed mysql and apache. But cannot install and access phpmyadmin.

Comment: What happens when you try to load it?

Comment: It's throwing: `Not Found

The requested URL /phpmyadmin was not found on this server.
Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80`

Comment: Does it go through the phpmyadmin install process without errors?

Comment: I don't see the line in which you install phpmyadmin is in the mysql-server package?

Comment: It loads index.php file and project folders but it doesn't load phpmyadmin.

Comment: Can you connect to mysql from the command line using `mysql -u root -p`?

Comment: I don't know linux mint but on other delian-based distribution you should explicitly issue something like:  sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin.

Comment: @terencehill that dpkg command fails if it is not installed at all. `dpkg-query: package 'phpmyadmin' is not installed and no information is available`

Comment: It's showing: `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Comment: @JasonKennaly I guess you are right but the command that actually install phpmyadmin is missing

Comment: I think phpmyadmin is installed but mysql is not confugured yet. Did you assign a password to the mysql root user during installation?

Comment: How could I check password because I did it several times and I want to be sure what it is and if it is set?

Comment: When I ran : `sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin` - there is message that it is already installed.

Comment: You need to be able to run this command `mysql -u root -p` and get a `mysql>` prompt, then you will be ready to configure phpmadmin.

Comment: Have you tried running `sudo mysql_secure_installation`?

Comment: There is this error for access denied...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101016/discussion-between-jason-kennaly-and-mistery-girl).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same issue with linux mint 18. I have uninstalled phpmyadmin completely from my system and followed the below link to install and configure php, mysql and phpmyadmin. Hope the link given below will help you (*link is for ubuntu, but definitely work with mint*);

[how-to-install-and-configure-apachephpmysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu](http://connectwww.com/how-to-install-and-configure-apachephpmysql-and-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu/727/)

Comment: Thanks very much. This link helped me as well.

Answer (score 10):

**Open the terminal, type:**

```
sudo gedit /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

**and below the end of file, at the last line, type**

```
include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Comment: You should include restarting apache.  service apache2 restart

Answer (score 6):

Just ran into this issue myself.

Normally, the Debian (apt) installation stuff installs the software including some basic defaults. The install script asked if it should configure apache2, so it seems this is a bug, since when I got done, gornicht.

Everything else looked good, from phpinfo on. Searching failed to reveal any signs that phpmyinfo was installed in apache2, while MySQL had the appropriate changes.

My solution was as simple as

```
ln /etc/phpmyinfo/apache.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/001-phpmyinfo
```

This hard links the default configuration from phpmyadmin's directory over to Apache2's. 
(Obviously, if you're running lighttp or apache 1,  targets and destinations must change.) This adds the phpmyadmin "site" to the list that Apache2 serves. You should look at it for edification.

Anyhow, after that,

```
sudo apache2ctl restart

sudo mysqld restart
```

should probably get `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` working as expected.

(By all means, toss out constructive criticisms. I'm no expert on this.)

Comment: Thank you all for answers, in fact I succeeded in installing it. I had to reinstall it and it's working now.